# Can I setup Skype so it changes status automatically on a schedule?

Tags: skype

I would like to set up Skype so it changes status automatically to *available* in the morning, and to *do-not-disturb* or *invisible* every day at 16.30. Is there any way to do so?

I searched for such feature on the Skype interface and menus, but had not found anything. I also Googled a lot, but I did not find relevant answers. It seems that Skype can be set up easily to change status to AWAY after some idle time, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Maybe there is a plugin that can do that? Or maybe there is an external program that can change Skype's status on a schedule?

Comment: This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. There is an assumption here that you have attempted something before asking. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including research you have done. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are hiding that feature in Skype For Business (this is Microsoft we are talking about) and what SfB does is it pulls your status from whatever meeting you are scheduled to be in per your Outlook calendar. So, if you have a meeting set as "do not disturb" time, it will automatically show that status to your contacts.  Skype doesn't have direct calendar integration (that I have ever seen work) so it isn't able to accommodate that.

Comment: Jeff, how does one "have a meeting set as "do not disturb" time"?